# How do you use two where statements in on SQL command?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got some code that selects all the entries in a database between two dates, but I'd also like it to not select any with the "Removed" in the "Status" column. I can get it to do either or, but not both at once.

```
try {
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT Link, Type, Location, Urgency, Date, Time, Status, Days FROM reports WHERE truedate BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date");
$STH->execute(array(':start_date' => $start_date_variable, ':end_date' => $end_date_variable));


$rows = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<table>";

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Link'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Urgency'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Days'] . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

}catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So how do I use two where statements to narrow down my results?

Comment: after your WHERE clause, add an AND clause with another condition it it. WHERE this=that AND that=this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an `AND` operator before the `truedate` check as shown.

```
SELECT Link, Type, Location, Urgency, Date, Time, Status, Days FROM reports WHERE Status NOT LIKE '%Removed%' AND truedate BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your code with below

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT Link, Type, Location, Urgency, Date, Time, Status, Days FROM reports WHERE Status != :statusval AND truedate BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date");
$STH->execute(array(':statusval ' => 'Removed', ':start_date' => $start_date_variable, ':end_date' => $end_date_variable));
```